# In jquery, how can I show the result of a variable inside a <span>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

I am having a lot of trouble when directing the result of a variable to a span element. I don't know what¡s going on exactly, but I understand the mistake is likely to be in the way I'm connecting the variable with the span. However, I have recently started with javascript and I cannot target any mistake with accuracy.

The variable calculated is "a" and I want to take the numerical value to the span id="flec1".

I attach the relevant part of the code, which is part of a program that works with Flot charts.

```
<body>

<div style = "float: right; margin: 5px 10% 0 10%", id = "valor_flector">
                    Flector =  <span id="flec1"> 0 </span>  m x kN.<br>
</div>

function updateLegend() {
        updateLegendTimeout = null;

        var pos = latestPosition;

        var axes = plot.getAxes();
        if (pos.x < axes.xaxis.min || pos.x > axes.xaxis.max ||
            pos.y < axes.yaxis.min || pos.y > axes.yaxis.max)
            return;

        var i, j, dataset = plot.getData();
        var series1 = dataset[2];
        //var series2 = dataset[3];

            // find the nearest points, x-wise
            for (i = 0; i < series1.data.length; ++i)
                if (series1.data[i] > pos.x)
                    break;

            // now interpolate
            var a, p1 = series1.data[i - 1], p2 = series1.data[i];
            if (p1 == null)
                a = p2[1]/2;
            else if (p2 == null)
                a = p1[1]/2;
            else
                a = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * (pos.x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);

         **//probable mistake**
            var $a = $("#a.toFixed(2)");

        $("#flec1").text($a);

}        

</body>
```

Comment: Why on earth would you wrap a number in jQuery?

Comment: Just do `$("#flec1").text( a.toFixed(2) )`

Comment: just tried it, but it doesn's work. I cannot figure out why

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't really a description of, well, anything! Open the console and check for errors, tell us what you are getting, what you're expecting to get etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I will tell you on Monday about the console errors

Comment: is it the comma before the div id?

Comment: "...on Monday" Good luck with that!

Comment: Till Monday I cannot be back, and the files are in the other computer. I'm not in a hurry, so I will keep investigating

Comment: @PedroBernardo, maybe the comma is one of the errors, but as Arjit says below, I must have some more mistakes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2KB6Y/1/  This is a fiddle which doesn't show the graph, though it is perfectly shown in Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You do not need selector, simply call [numObj.toFixed(digits)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on `a`, *The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation, [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)*.

```
 var $a = $(a.toFixed(2));
```

**digits**

> The number of digits to appear after the decimal point; this may be a
>   value between 0 and 20, inclusive, and implementations may optionally
>   support a larger range of values. If this argument is omitted, it is
>   treated as 0.

Comment: Ok. On Monday I'll upload a fiddle. Now I'm driving home and the computer will remain in town. Thanks so much @Adil

Comment: You are welcome, just give me a reminder of fiddle then.

Comment: Adil, I'm back as promised

Comment: this the fiddle I've done, but the flot graph is not ploted. I can't understand why, cause it is perfectly plotted in Chrome and Firefox.   http://jsfiddle.net/2KB6Y/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of these two lines

```
var $a = $("#a.toFixed(2)");
    $("#flec1").text($a);
```

you can just write

```
$("#flec1").text(a.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: are u able to identify where exactly is the problem..it is becoz of the comma u are having in div tag ', id = "valor_flector;'..

Comment: i tried the same thing '$("#flec1").text(a.toFixed(2));' ..it works for me......I feel that there is some other problem..

Comment: I tried what u say, but it doesn't work to me. I also feel there must be something else wrong

Comment: actually, your proposal of $("#flec1").text(a.toFixed(2)); has finally worked. But now I gotta solve another strange problem related to non-continuous lines (those with a peak). I attach the fiddle, though the graph is not ploted